# MySQL query between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-sql

I can use some help with a query. I have two tables:

```
employee = {
  id,
  manager,

  data1,
}


hrm = {
 id,
 employee,

 data2,
};
```

The Query. I like to have all hrm records from the employees which have Tom as manager.

```
SELECT hrm.employee, hrm.data2 FROM hrm WHERE AND EXISTS  
(SELECT id from employee WHERE manager = 'TOM')
```

This gives me

```
Jan, data2
Piet, data2
```

Great! but I want more. :-) I also like to have the associated data1 column from employee.

```
Jan, data2, data1
Piet, data2, data1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the query you have definitely work? It looks like it will return all `hrm` if there is any employee with Tom as a manager.

Comment: No it didn't. Thanks for your input. Got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT hrm.employee, hrm.data2, employee.data1
FROM hrm
INNER JOIN employee ON (hrm.employee = employee.id)
WHERE employee.manager == "TOM";
```

Will give all `hrm`s associated with an employee with a manager "TOM". This assumes that `hrm` and `employee` are associated with the `hrm.employee` and `employee.id` fields.

Comment: +1 for the replaced EXISTS what is known to scale badly on large tables in MySQL because it could be rewritten by the MySQL optimizer into an IN statement with an correlated subquery